# Undefined method 'build_schedule' for object with a one-to-many relationship to schedule

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

In my Schedules Controller, I have the following method:

```
def create
    @schedule = current_user.team.create_schedule(params[:schedule])
    if @schedule.save
        flash[:success] = "Schedule created!"
        redirect_to current_user.team
    else
        flash[:error] = "Sorry! Something went wrong."
        render new_schedule_path
    end
end
```

When I try to create a schedule, I get an error on the second line: undefined method `create_schedule' for #

However, the team model has many schedules and the schedule model belongs to team so I'm not sure the problem is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `create_schedule` method would be if it was a has_one association. It should be `@schedule = current_user.team.schedules.build(params[:schedule])`